# Why does a clean git clone fix a failing build?

Tags: git, webpack, continuous-integration

I have a project which depends on webpack to build. I have a new branch from a teammember which I checked out and did a `git reset --hard` on. After running the build, it errors. When I do a clean `git clone` and check out the new branch, it works. What gives? How can I make it so I don't have to completely clone the project again?

The errors I get are as follows:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./webpack.config.ts:312:5
    TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type '{}'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./webpack.config.ts:317:103
    TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type '{}'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./webpack.config.ts:545:5
    TS2339: Property 'getProperty' does not exist on type 'LoDashExplicitObjectWrapper<NodeConfig>'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./webpack.config.ts:545:17
    TS7006: Parameter 'n' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

The steps are as follows: (this generates errors)

`git checkout extract_css`
`git reset --hard`
`yarn`

Or, with a clean repo: (this works)

`git clone <url> new`
`cd new`
`git checkout extract_css`
`yarn`

Comment: What error do you get? Did you do the same steps after the `reset` as after the `clone`? One possible reason is that `node_modules` are different and need to be (re-)installed, but without the error, there is no way for us to tell.

Comment: @MichaelJungo I've updated the post! It may be important to mention that our `node_modules` contains a few custom libraries which are committed in our repository, the rest gets populated by `yarn`.

Comment: What does a `git status` give you after the `git reset --hard`. A git reset doesn't clean the directory of files that are not tracked. A `git clean` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) will set the working directory to be 'exactly' like your repository checkout.

Comment: `git status` = `working directory clean`. `git clean -f`, then `yarn`: same error...

Comment: Without `-x`, `git clean` will specifically *not* remove explicitly-ignored files. Depending on the build system and the way you use it, that could leave many already-built files that are based on obsolete inputs. After `git clean -fdx` you should have the same situation as a fresh clone (but beware of submodules). (I know nothing of webpack in particular but if it cannot or does not get dependencies correct, this would explain the problem.)

Comment: @torek thank you so much. This has solved my problem. If you want to make this an actual answer I'll gladly select it as the fix!

Comment: @torek unfortunately, this doesn't fix my issue on the CI-part of the deployment cycle. I do the `git clean -fdx` on there, but the same errors appear... Any ideas?

Comment: @torek (again :p): it seems that the `git clean -fdx` did work. My latest issue was because of webpack, which used an older version than I needed. Thanks again for the great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `-x`.  The rest of this is expanded from [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901561/why-does-a-clean-git-clone-fix-a-failing-build?noredirect=1#comment72907411_42901561)

It's important to consider precisely *which* files `git clean` cleans.  As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) says, it:

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not
>   under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the `-x` option
>   is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example, be
>   useful to remove all build products.

The first paragraph leaves undefined what it means to be "not under version control".  The *second* paragraph, however, gives us a strong clue, and the description of the `-d` argument cements it—provided, that is, that we have a clear definition of "untracked":

> `-d`
>
>   Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. ...

There's a nice, simple Git-specific definition of tracked vs untracked: an *untracked* file is one that is not in the *index* (and hence of course a *tracked* file is one that *is* in the index).

Remember that Git's index is *where you build the next commit*.  The index starts out matching the current commit—the one you ran `git checkout` on, i.e., the tip of the current branch.  Every file that is in that commit, is also in the current index.  Git copied the file *from* the commit, *to* the index, and then on to the *work-tree*, which puts them into a form the rest of the computer can deal with (the internal form inside commits and in the index is essentially a Git-only form).

It's quite normal for the work-tree to hold additional files that are *not* in the index.  Any time we use programs that build things from our sources—for instance, `.o` or `.so` files from C or other compiled code, or `.pyc` or `.pyo` byte-compiled Python files, or anything else often called [build artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development)) these days—we end up with things that are not, and should not be, version-controlled.  We do not add them to the index, so they are untracked.

Git, however, likes to split these up in various ways.  Untracked files can be a nuisance: Git keeps pestering us, warning that this file and that one are untracked, should we maybe add them?  We know we should not, so we tell Git to please *shut up* about that, by listing the files—by path name, or file pattern such as `*.o`, or whatever it takes—in a `.gitignore` file.  That makes Git shut up.

But it also changes the way `git clean` treats these files.  By default, `git clean` only removes the ones it would *complain about*.  Since we mostly tell Git to *ignore* build artifacts, a plain `git clean -f` won't remove them.  We need `git clean -fx`.

Note that when a untracked files live within a directory (or "folder") that has no *tracked* files in it, Git normally lumps them all together for reporting purposes, and says that the entire directory is untracked.  In this case, `git clean -fx` will still leave those untouched: you need `git clean -dfx` to remove them, and then also the now-empty directory itself.  (Note that if there are any tracked files within that directory, this rule no longer applies.)

As the description mentions, this all has to be run from the top level of the work-tree, since it starts "from the current directory".  It's also important to note that any sub-Gits or submodules will prevent `git clean` from working within that sub-directory; for these cases, it's probably best to repeat the `git clean` in that separate Git repository.  (E.g., with submodules you could use `git submodule foreach` to visit each one and clean it.)

Comment: Excellent explanation of the behaviour of git, and why your answer works for my issue. I wanted to be sure I had a clean directory on our CI servers, because our provider doesn't seem to properly clear them once in a while. It's probably fixable without the `git clean -fdx`, but it works. Thanks a lot!